# Google map not getting centered

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The google map i am using does not get centered about the mean point i have calculated.
The code for the initialization is given. The map appears to be zoomed out a lot and its center far off from the center i have calculated. The mean appears in the extreme top left of the map. What is the problem here?

I am displaying the map in Bootstrap modal.

```
function initializeMap()
{
var xMean = 0.0;
var yMean = 0.0;

for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++)
{
    xMean += parseFloat(points[i][0]);
    yMean += parseFloat(points[i][1]);
}

xMean /= parseFloat(points.length);
yMean /= parseFloat(points.length);

var myMean = new google.maps.LatLng(xMean, yMean);

var mapOptions = {
  zoom:17,
  center:myMean
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i<points.length;i++) {
  path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(points[i][0],points[i][1]));
  bounds.extend(path[i]);
};

map.fitBounds(bounds);

//Displaying the markers
var marker;
for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: path[i],
    map: map
  });
}

//Displaying the path
for (var i = 0; i<path.length-1; i++) {
    var start = path[i];
    var end = path[i+1];
    requestDirections(start,end);
}
}
```

Comment: _Sounds_ like a zero size div problem (top left corner), but you haven't provided enough information to tell

Answer (score 0):

by using:

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

you seem to overwrite `myMean` coordinates